# Can I manipulate elements on index page from a component in angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I was wondering if I can manipulate elements on index page (angular2) from component?  The scenario  that I'm having is that, since index.html is not the one that was set as template in any of my component, I can't seem to find a way to manipulate it. Please below sample.

index.html

```
<div *ngIf="showMe" id="test"></div> <!-- the element that I want to manipulate -->
<myapp></myapp>
```

Sample.ts

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'myapp',
    templateUrl:'sample.html', 
    encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
    })
    ngOnInit() { 
     showMe = false;
    }
```

Above is not working but pretty much the Idea that I wan't to do . As much as possible I don't want to use other libs. However that's my last option (use jquery just to manipulate) in case I won't find any luck on this one.

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Why not simply putting it in your `myapp` component ?

Comment: use services to communicate between components
sampleComponent -> serviceComponent <- appCompponent

Comment: I thought about that and that would be easy, but for this one, I can't because  I am implementing a multi-component on a single index . So I'd like to access a div from other component also. More like of a global way.

Comment: @DamianMartyniuk that's a good idea also but that wont make me access a element from index . Thanks for the idea .

Comment: you can just access that div using js document.getElementbyId like methods inside your app component or even from other components.

Comment: @FahadNisar , that's true it will work but it would be much sweeter for me if i can fully utilize angular2 functionalities. Anwyways, thanks for your idea.